# D3 js chart issue

Tags: d3.js

```
can anyone help me with this?why the line begins under xScale?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2gjw4wy/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `yScale` to mean two different things: both bar Y-position (54) and bar height (61). But those values aren't the same for most bars. Change line 61 to something like: `return (styles.h-styles.padding - yScale(d[1]));`.

Also, using `min` as the upper bound of the range for `yScale` doesn't really make sense because that's a data (input) value, not a pixel (output) value. It would make more sense to make that line (22): `.range([styles.h-styles.padding, styles.padding])`